# how to hide empty/blank row in datagrid on windows forms

Tags: c#, forms, datagrid

I have some `DataGrid` and there is always empty row like on picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HWKp.png

Is there any way to hide this blank row in `DataGrid`?

Comment: just disable adding a new row??

Comment: @John no, this is for `DataGridView` but I need for `DataGrid`

Comment: @sLw yeah, just to disable adding new row, only display information

Answer (score 0):

Just set this attribute as true.

```
myDataGrid.ReadOnly = true;
```